# How to encode this link?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

Need help to remove the \ on this link in php.

[image]

Comment: This string comes from an undecoded JSON?

Comment: @Syscall Yes it is.

Comment: So, why don't you use [json_decode()](https://php.net/json_decode)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use str_replace function in available in PHP.

str_replace ('Find what you want to replace', 'Replace with ', 'Your array or string variable');

example:

```
$str = "<your link>"
str_replace("\","",$str)
```

Comment: This code have a syntax error, that's why I've downvoted.